# Run executable file from a different user

Tags: linux, centos, executable, rpm, init.d

While creating an rpm spec file I have created a new user and group in the %pre section. This new user does not however have permission to login from from shell for security purposes. Now when I install the rpm this new user is successfully created. However, I wish to start the installed rpm service with the newly created user. Currently I simply write; 'filePath/file.exe file.cfg' to execute the file.exe with its configuration file i.e. file.cfg in my 'init.d' file to start the service. How can I modify this command to start the same service but with the user that I created while installing the rpm? Basically I want to execute the program in my init.d file but through a different user, like I would have done with sudo if my required user was the super user. Any feedback will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial starting point both for installing the rpm and for running the service *is* privileged.  For instance, on my CentOS 6 machine, I see in `/etc/passwd`

```
games:x:12:100:games:/usr/games:/sbin/nologin
```

but running as root, I can do this:

```
$ sudo -u games /bin/sh
sh-4.1$ echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
sh-4.1$ id
uid=12(games) gid=100(users) groups=100(users) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
sh-4.1$ cd
sh-4.1$ pwd
/usr/games
```

In your service script, you can use `sudo` to run a given process as another user (though a quick check of the same machine does not show this being done).

@msuchy points out that `runuser` may be preferable.  I see that this is relatively recent (according to [Ubuntu runuser command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169441/ubuntu-runuser-command), appeared in [util-linux 2.23](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.23/v2.23-ReleaseNotes) -- [lacking a date](http://invisible-island.net/personal/changelogs.html#timestamps) makes release notes less than useful...).  The oblique comments in its documentation [about PAM](http://www.flashnux.com/en/centos/5/5.4/man1/runuser.1.html) make it sound as if this circumvents some of the security checks. Perhaps someone has a better comment about *that*.

Comment: From scripts you should not call sudo, but rather "runuser [options] [-] [user [argument...]]"